# Count filled SQL array fields PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I´m fetching an array from a mysql query like this.

```
$viewerSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `this` WHERE id = ". 
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id]) ."");
$pageData = mysql_fetch_array($pageSql);
```

I get an array with like 40 entries, i want to check seven of them by name if they are filled.

What i´ve tried and what I thought about so far:

```
$oioi = 0;

                            while($oioi<7){
                            $oioi++;
                            $pic = "pic".$oioi;
                            $active="";
                            $path = "./upload/objectoffers/$viewerData[id]/$pic";
                            $picDesc = "pic".$oi."Desc";
                            $picArray = '$viewerData['.$pic.']';
                            echo $pic."<br>";
                            echo $picArray."<p>";
                            if(!empty($path)){
                            if($oioi==1){$active = "active";}?>
                            <div class="item <?=$active;?>">
                                <img style="width: 100%;" src="./images/<?=$viewerData[$pic];?>" alt="<?=$viewerData[$picDesc]?>">
                            </div>
                            <?
                            }}
                          ?>
```

But this doesn´t work because: `$path` is NEVER empty...I wanted to avoid to write "`if(!empty)`" for every single `$viewerData[pic1]` to `$viewerData[pic7]` array manual...

that´s why i´m here...

maybe you can help me improving this or offer some tips.

Thanks!

edit: This is what I get as "output":

```
pic1
$viewerData[pic1]

pic2
$viewerData[pic2]

pic3
$viewerData[pic3]

pic4
$viewerData[pic4]

pic5
$viewerData[pic5]

pic6
$viewerData[pic6]

pic7
$viewerData[pic7]
```

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are no longer maintained and are [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which MySQL API to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use file_exists instead !empty:

```
$oioi = 0;

while ($oioi < 7) {
    $oioi++;
    $pic = "pic" . $oioi;
    $active = "";
    $path = "./upload/objectoffers/$viewerData[id]/$pic";
    $picDesc = "pic" . $oi . "Desc";
    $picArray = '$viewerData[' . $pic . ']';

    echo $pic . "<br>";
    echo $picArray . "<p>";

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        if ($oioi == 1) {
            $active = "active";
        }
        ?>
        <div class="item <?= $active; ?>">
            <img style="width: 100%;" src="./images/<?= $viewerData[$pic]; ?>" alt="<?= $viewerData[$picDesc] ?>">
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: ouh why didn´t i thought about this...thanks! That should do the trick! This is like 10 times easier as all i got in back of my head...thanks! Edit: I´ll mark is as right as I can!